# Data-binding issue binding a table with add / remove

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am populating a complex view-model using MVC4. I am populating like this

```
var job = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.job));
var customer = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.customer));
var listTasks = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tasks));
var estimateMaterials = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.estimateMaterials));
var estimate = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.estimate));

var JobPost = {
    customer: customer,
    job: job,
    listTasks: ko.observableArray(listTasks),
    estimateMaterials: ko.observableArray(estimateMaterials),
    estimate: ko.observable()
};
ko.applyBindings(JobPost,  document.getElementById("update-job-form"));
```

Now, the object `estimateMaterials` is being populated to a row. And to that row, I want to add `Remove` to each row and `Add button` at the bottom of the table like this

[image: Image of the table]

Then I saw, [rniemeyer wonderful fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/adNuR/) on adding / deleting row easily.
The forked fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/tDV9k/

In that there is a snippet like this

```
self.addLine = function() { self.lines.push(new CartLine()) };
self.removeLine = function(line) { self.lines.remove(line) };
```

I would like to implement something like that to my observable array
`estimateMaterials: ko.observableArray(estimateMaterials)`

Is this possible to add methods like this?

P.S: I am adding / deleting by cloning a row / removing closest tr respectively using jquery. I am seeking a cleaner way.

**Update:**

The main problem I am facing here is how to access the object in the `observableArray`

Comment: Yeah, it is possible to add them, but what kind of problems do you have? You get an error? Something is not working? Or what else?

Comment: @nemesv: I am sorry if you still don't understand how clueless I am doing it. I think it could be done. But I dont know where to add it. I have described my thought processes here. I have done a thousands of iteration and finally abstracted the problem to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have understood your question incorrectly, have a look at the below and let me know if you have any questions

```
function EstimateMaterialLine() {
    var self = this;
    self.EstMatlID = ko.observable();
    //other observables to follow
}
var job = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.job));
var customer = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.customer));
var listTasks = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Tasks));
var estimateMaterials = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.estimateMaterials));
var estimate = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.estimate));

var JobPostViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.customer = ko.observable(customer);
    self.job = ko.observable(job);
    self.listTasks = ko.observableArray(listTasks);
    self.estimateMaterials = ko.observableArray(estimateMaterials);
    self.estimate = ko.observable(estimate);
    self.removeEstimateMaterial = function(line) { 
        self.estimateMaterials.remove(line) 
    };
    self.addEstimateMaterial = function() { 
        self.estimateMaterials.push(new EstimateMaterialLine()) 
    };
};
var model = new JobPostViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model,  document.getElementById("update-job-form"));
```

So lets say you have a table, then you can use it like so:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: estimateMaterials">
    <tr>
       <td> <input type="button" value="delete" data-bind="click: $root.removeEstimateMaterials"/> </td>
    <tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add" data-bind="click: $root.addEstimateMaterials"/>
```

Comment: thanks mate. this is exactly what I did afterwards. Let me improvise this a little. feel free to rollback

Comment: @naveen no be my guest, you know your code better than I will ever do

Comment: your modesty amaze me. thanks again. I am very new to `knockoutjs`. Just a month. That too not full-time. Its very powerful. I made only one change `estimateMaterials.push(new EstimateMaterialLine()) ` rather than object. It will guarantee a new object reference right?

Comment: Yeah I have been using it exclusively for about a year and a half now, and will never look back, am starting to combine it with some other cool things I came across the other day, you should check out breeze.js with knockout and entity framework in .NET it is amazing